# Missing channel_id in Inventory Edit Entry URL breaks Structure

Tags: expresso-store, structure, url

We have encountered issues when running Exp-resso 2.5.1 in tandem with Structure 3.3.17 when accessing the Control Panel Inventory page.

The $product->channel_id that is requested on line 94 of InventoryController.php does not exist, and therefore when the link to edit an Inventory item is clicked, the channel_id is omitted.

Typically this does not cause problems, however when using Structure and editing a channel entry directly from the Inventory page, the lack of a channel_id in the URL string seems to break something with Structure. This can typically be fixed by editing the channel entry in Structure and saving it without making changes, but our clients are often unable to recall these simple steps.

Can I request that the following edit be made to the official build. On line 43 of the file:

```
system/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Cp/InventoryController.php
```

REPLACE

```
->select(array('store_products.*', 'channel_titles.title', $this->ee->store->db->raw('SUM(`stock_level`) AS `total_stock`')))
```

WITH

```
->select(array('store_products.*', 'channel_titles.title', 'channel_titles.channel_id', $this->ee->store->db->raw('SUM(`stock_level`) AS `total_stock`')))
```

Adding the channel_titles.channel_id column to the query should resolve this issue in the future.

Thanks for your time and effort put into this addon,

Phil Dowson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature request are better sent directly to the developer. You have 2 options for that you could go to their [support form](http://www.devdemon.com/support/form/) or by emailing them directly at info@devdemon.com